# regex numbers like 1.1k

Tags: php, regex

in regex `\d+` match all numbers, but it doesn't match numbers like `1k` or `1.4k` how should I make a regex to count that numbers too?

What i want:

VALID:

- 1.1K
- 1.2K
- 1.0K
- 1K

INVALID:

- 1.1

I am new to regex and I don't know how to start

Comment: just to clarify: \d does not match numbers but digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add `K` to your regex

```
/(\d|.\d)+K?/g
```

and i recommend to you to use a tool like that [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Cool thanks, but it did not count normal numbers like 5 20 48 without that dot and "K" rule

Comment: but you wanted any number with K at the end

Comment: it seems i miss understood you , could explain more

Comment: i writed "should I make a regex to count that numbers **too**?"

Comment: so numers with k and without k  in one rule

Comment: @MrBartusek , check it again i have updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
\d+(\.\d+)?K
```

- `\d+` - Matches digits one or more
- `(\.\d+)?` -Matches `.` followed by digits. `?` makes it optional.
- `k` - Matches `K`

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ySLUSt/3/)